# How to call ".approve()" function of a token which ABI I don't have? In web3.js/ethers

Tags: web3js, erc-20, ethers.js, abi, erc-20-approve

I need to call `.approve()` function of a token which I address I know but which ABI I don't have. How to do it? Will it be enough to create ABI string which will contain the signature of `.approve()` function only? If not, how else then?

It's on the client side, and using `ethers` or `web3js` library.

Answer (score 1):

if you only need to call the approve function you can use any standard erc20 abi, or as you said you can just make a custom abi that only has the approve function